# How to detect when the drawer is opened in react-navigation?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm using react-navigation's DrawerNavigator in my app. I would like to detect when a user drags open the side menu so that i can perform a certain action, e.g dismiss an opened Keyboard.
How can i do this? i can't seem to find a solution in the docs. Thank you.

### Here is my code

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import { Icon } from 'react-native-elements';
import { DrawerNavigator, StackNavigator, addNavigationHelpers } from 'react-navigation';


//redux related imports
import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { Provider, connect } from 'react-redux';

import Attendance from './containers/pages/Attendance';
import Fees from './containers/pages/Fees';
import Exams from './containers/pages/Exams';
import InitializeUser from './containers/pages/InitializeUser';
import Landing from './Landing';
import Login from './containers/pages/Login';
import Search from './containers/pages/Search';
import Staff from './containers/pages/Staff';
import Stats from './containers/pages/Stats';
import Students from './containers/pages/Students';
import Verification from './containers/pages/verify';
import ProfileDetail from './components/pages/ProfileDetail';
import FeesDetail from './containers/pages/FeesDetails';


import MainReport from './containers/pages/Reports/Main_Report';
import AcademicDetails from './containers/pages/Reports/Student_Academic_Details';
import { Constants } from './config';
import ResultsLanding from './containers/pages/Reports/ResultsLanding';
import { CustomDrawerContentComponent } from '../src/components/base/SideMenu';


const screenWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;
const MainPages = DrawerNavigator({
  StudentsPage: {
    path: '/Students',
    screen: Students
  },
  SearchPage: {
    path: '/Seacrh',
    screen: Search
  },

  Staff: {
    path: '/Staff',
    screen: Staff
  },

  Fees: {
    path: '/Fees',
    screen: Fees
  },
  Stats: {
    path: '/Stats',
    screen: Stats
  },
  Results: {
    screen: ResultsLanding,
    navigationOptions: {
      tintColor: 'red',
      flex: 1,
      drawerIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
        <Icon
          name="content-paste"
          color={tintColor}
        />
      )
    }
  },
  Attendance:
  {
    path: '/Attendance',
    screen: Attendance
  },
},
  {
    initialRouteName: 'StudentsPage',
    contentOptions: {
      activeTintColor: Constants.ui.THEME,
      activeBackgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.1)',
      inactiveTintColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.6)',
      labelStyle: {
        fontSize: 12,
        marginLeft: 10,
      },
    },

    drawerWidth: screenWidth > 320 ? 300 : 250,
    contentComponent: CustomDrawerContentComponent

  });

export const Navigator = StackNavigator({
  LandingPage: {
    screen: Landing,
    navigationOptions: {
      header: null
    }
  },
  LoginPage: {
    screen: Login,
    navigationOptions: {
      header: null
    },
  },
  ProfileDetailPage: {
    screen: ProfileDetail,
    headerMode: 'screen',
    navigationOptions: {
      header: null
    }
  },
  FeesDetailPage:
  {
    screen: FeesDetail,
    navigationOptions: {
      header: null
    },
  },
  VerifyPage: {
    screen: Verification,
    navigationOptions: {
      header: null
    },
  },
  InitUserPage: {
    screen: InitializeUser,
    navigationOptions: {
      header: null
    },
  },
  MainPages: {
    screen: MainPages,
    navigationOptions: {
      header: null
    }
  },

  MainReportPage: {
    screen: MainReport,
    navigationOptions: {
      header: null
    }
  },
  ExamsMainPage: {
    screen: Exams,
    navigationOptions: {
      header: null
    }
  },
  AcademicDetailsPage: {
    screen: AcademicDetails,
    navigationOptions: {
      header: null
    }
  },

});  

const initialState = MainPages.router.getStateForAction(
  MainPages.router.getActionForPathAndParams('StudentsPage'));  

const navReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  const nextState = MainPages.router.getStateForAction(action, state);
  return nextState || state;
}; 

const appReducer = combineReducers({
  nav: navReducer
});

class App extends React.Component {
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    console.warn('nextProps: ', JSON.stringify(nextProps, null, 4));
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <MainPages 
        navigation={addNavigationHelpers({
        dispatch: this.props.dispatch,
        state: this.props.nav,
      })} />
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  nav: state.nav
});

const AppWithNavigationState = connect(mapStateToProps)(App);

const store = createStore(appReducer);

class Root extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <AppWithNavigationState />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

### Here is a screenshot of the error i get when i run the code

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to detect the DrawerNavigator's open and close side menu actions by following the [Redux Integration](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/guides/redux) guide and modifying it to use a DrawerNavigator instead of StackNavigator. Here is what I have inside my `index.ios.js` file. Near the bottom within the `App` class I use `componentWillReceiveProps` which displays a warning every time the drawer opens or closes.

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  Image,
  Text,
  View,
  ScrollView
} from 'react-native';
import {DrawerNavigator, DrawerItems, addNavigationHelpers } from 'react-navigation';
import { Provider, connect } from 'react-redux'
import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux'

class MyHomeScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    drawerLabel: 'Home',
    drawerIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
      <Image
        source={require('./images/Groups.png')}
        style={{tintColor: tintColor, width: 26, height: 26}}/>
    ),
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Home Screen</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class MyNotificationsScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    drawerLabel: 'Notifications',
    drawerIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
      <Image
        source={require('./images/Events.png')}
        style={{tintColor: tintColor, width: 26, height: 26}}/>
    ),
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Notifications Screen</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const NavDemo = DrawerNavigator({
  Home: { screen: MyHomeScreen },
  Notifications: { screen: MyNotificationsScreen }
}, {
  tabBarOptions: {
    activeTintColor: '#e91e63',
  },
  drawerWidth: 200,
  drawerPosition: 'left',
  contentComponent: props => <ScrollView><DrawerItems {...props} /></ScrollView>
});

const initialState = NavDemo.router.getStateForAction(NavDemo.router.getActionForPathAndParams('Home'));

const navReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  const nextState = NavDemo.router.getStateForAction(action, state);
  return nextState || state;
};

const appReducer = combineReducers({
  nav: navReducer
});

class App extends React.Component {
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    console.warn('nextProps: ' + JSON.stringify(nextProps, null, 4))
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <NavDemo navigation={addNavigationHelpers({
        dispatch: this.props.dispatch,
        state: this.props.nav,
      })} />
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  nav: state.nav
});

const AppWithNavigationState = connect(mapStateToProps)(App);

const store = createStore(appReducer);

class Root extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <AppWithNavigationState />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('NavDemo', () => Root);
```

When I open the drawer and expand the warning `nextProps` looks like this:

[image]

And then after I close the drawer, the new warning appears like this:

[image]

`nextProps.nav` is an object with two keys, `routes` and `index`. When the drawer opens, `index` becomes `1`, and when it closes, index becomes `0`.

Using that information, you can add an if statement to perform your necessary actions when the drawer opens.

Comment: Thanks a lot Pat Needham I'll check it out and give you the feedback. Thanks again for the early response.

Comment: nope i want to send you my code and the screenshot of the error i got so you check it out for me please

Comment: Pat could you please check it out for me ? if there is something you do not get please lemme know asap i need to just dismiss the keyboard when the drawer is open since react navigation does not automatically dismiss it for me. what a pain....

Comment: @danieldoe I looked at the screenshot error message - does that occur immediately after opening the app or at a certain point like opening or closing the nav drawer? Also, from another Terminal / Command Prompt window can you run `react-native log-android` to get more detailed logging? That might be more useful than the screenshot error's message, which I don't think provides anything clues because I don't see `action` or `type` being used anywhere in your code snippet. Also try searching the project directory for where all instances of `action.type` are being used

Comment: ok Boss i am actually writing the code with my professor i will go through it with him because it has to work per the react-navigation redux integration docs. Thanks a lot Pat i sure appreciate it. well if you have an alternative way to dismiss the keyboard when the drawer is  opened feel free to fill me in. Till then Thanks again for your time.

Answer (score 10):

Simply, if you use react-navigation v5 -

```
import { useIsDrawerOpen } from '@react-navigation/drawer'

const isOpen: boolean = useIsDrawerOpen()
```

then you have to subscribe on "isOpen" flag by hook useEffect:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (!isOpen) {
      // Your dismiss logic here 
    }
}, [isOpen])
```

Your custom Drawer can look like [DrawerContent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9p7Js.png)

Hope it helped

Comment: The hook is now called `useDrawerStatus` and its value is a string (either `'open'` or `'closed'`) refer to [this part](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/upgrading-from-5.x/#drawer-status-is-now-a-string-instead-of-a-boolean) of the doc

Answer (score 1):

This is an old thread, but I wanted to share how I managed to do this.

Add the following code inside your app (preferably where you create the DraweStack.)

```js
const defaultGetStateForAction = DrawerStack.router.getStateForAction;
DrawerStack.router.getStateForAction = (action, state) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "Navigation/DRAWER_OPENED":
    case "Navigation/MARK_DRAWER_ACTIVE":
      Keyboard.dismiss();
      break;
  }

  return defaultGetStateForAction(action, state);
};
```

There are various **action.type**s. For instance:

- Navigation/MARK_DRAWER_ACTIVE is called when the drawer starts to open
- Navigation/MARK_DRAWER_SETTLING is called when the drawer has opened.
- etc.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

- this.props.navigation.state.isDrawerOpen => true/false

Answer (score 0):

In navigation 6x, you can do the following to get the drawer status.

```
import { useDrawerStatus } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
const isDrawerOpen = useDrawerStatus() === 'open';
```

here is the full documentation. https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-navigator/#events